# SwiftUI: How to Update NavigationView Detail Screens?

Tags: rest, swiftui

I've got an app that gets a list of vehicles from a REST backend server. It then uses that list to build a list of vehicles that can be tapped to show the details about one of them:

```
@State private var selectedVehicle: Vehicle?
@Binding var vehicles: [Vehicle]

List {
  NavigationView {

    ForEach( vehicles ) { vehicle in
            NavigationLink( destination: VehicleDetailScreen( vehicle: vehicle ),
                            tag: vehicle,
                            selection: self.$selectedVehicle ) {
                                Text( vehicle.name )
            }
    }
  }
}

struct VehicleDetailScreen: View {    
    var vehicle: Vehicle

    var body: some View {
       // Lots of rendering code omitted
    }

}
```

So far, so good. This works nicely. The problem arises when we fetch updated information from the server. Updating the bound `vehicles` property works great for updating the list. But the detail screen is still showing data that's no longer relevant.

My first thought was just to pop the detail view off of the NavigationView. Unfortunately, SwiftUI doesn't provide any reliable way that I can find to do this in a two-column view on the iPad.

My next thought was that we needed to pass the vehicle in to VehicleDetailScreen as a @Binding too so that we can update it. But this is tough to do as well because we would need a reference to that binding so that we can cram updated values into it. The only way I can think of to do that would be to rework our network and model object code entirely so that it works like CoreData, keeping objects in memory and updating them with new values from the server, rather than generating new objects. This would be a good deal of effort, and obviously isn't something I'm keen to do if there's another option.

So I'm kind of stuck on this. Any thoughts/ideas/suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: I dont think we need to look at `VehicleDetailScreen`. How are you updating the `vehicles` property? Show us code around this

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the concept of `@Binding` is somewhat confusing. From a `@State var` (parent view), to `@Binding var` (child view).
A `struct` Hashable to facilitate and reorder the elements of the array `[Vehicle]`.

Something like this:

```
struct Vehicle: Hashable {
    var name:String
    //var otherItem: Any
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var vehicle: Vehicle //the struct of your REST
    @State var vehicles: [Vehicle] // the array of your REST

    var body: some View {
        List {
          NavigationView {
            ForEach(vehicles, id:\.self) { item in // loop the array to get every single item conform to the struct
                NavigationLink( destination: VehicleDetailScreen(vehicle: self.$vehicle)) { // here to pass the binding
                    Text("\(self.vehicle.name)")
                }
            }
          }
        }
    }
}

//detail view
struct VehicleDetailScreen: View {
    @Binding var vehicle: Vehicle // here the binding
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(vehicle.name)")
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually fix the problem, alas, as _something_ has to be responsible for updating that vehicle object. Also, within the ForEach, you're not displaying the name of the current vehicle in the loop, but always displaying the name of the vehicle that's a property. :(

Comment: @SeanMcMains try to check [dynamicMemberLookup](https://swiftbysundell.com/tips/combining-dynamic-member-lookup-with-key-paths)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your detail views to update when data changes, you will have to make use of bindings.

As far as architecture goes, I would suggest to create so called *Stores* that hold data which can be used in multiple views. This, in combination with some static provider for Stores, makes it that you can easily access and modify data anywhere, and let your views update automatically.

When using UIKit, you would manually refresh data by calling `reloadTable` for instance. In SwiftUI this is not done. You could hypothetically manually trigger the view to update, but I would advice against this, as it is not the way SwiftUI was intended.

I've modified your code to show an example of this:

```
class StoreProvider {
    static let carStore = CarStore()
}

class CarStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var vehicles: [Vehicle] = [Vehicle(id: "car01", name: "Porsche", year: 2016), Vehicle(id: "car02", name: "Lamborghini", year: 2002)]
}

struct Vehicle: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: String
    var name: String
    var year: Int
}

struct CarOverview: View {
    @ObservedObject var store = StoreProvider.carStore
    @State var selectedVehicle: Vehicle?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(store.vehicles.indices) { vehicleIndex in
                    NavigationLink(destination: VehicleDetailScreen(vehicle: self.$store.vehicles[vehicleIndex])) {
                        Text(self.store.vehicles[vehicleIndex].name)
                    }.onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedVehicle = self.store.vehicles[vehicleIndex]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct VehicleDetailScreen: View {
    @Binding var vehicle: Vehicle

    func updateValues() {
        vehicle.year = Int.random(in: 1990..<2020)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(vehicle.name)
            Text("Year: ") + Text(vehicle.year.description)
        }.onTapGesture(perform: updateValues)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this example. Using the index to work through the collection rather than just ForEach with each of the values _in_ the collection feels a little weird to me, but I was able to get things working fine with that approach. Thank you for your ideas!

Comment: Hmm, and now I'm getting bitten my this approach. If I have 12 items in the list, select the 12th, and then the REST call updates the list to only have 6 items, the binding is still trying to resolve to the 12th item and causes a hard crash. :(

Comment: True, this does not work with deleting items because `ForEach(_ Range)` only works with constant data. You could try making the Vehicle struct an `ObservableObject `, and then using ForEach on vehicles without the indices, and define the vehicle property in the detail view as `@ObservedObject` instead of @Binding